# Combining 2 queries into 1, so i dont have to do vlookup in excel

Tags: sql-server

The first query gives me hit count for reports. However I need to grab the sharepoint library name using the second query where I copied the ReportID from first query and supplied to 2nd query. Is there a way to combined these 2 queries (they use separate db) and get all the fields from first query and just the DirName field from 2nd query so I dont have copy each output in excel and do a vlookup

**1st Query:**

```
USE MSBI_reportingService
SELECT        ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, COUNT(*) AS HitCount, Catalog.Name, ExecutionLogStorage.UserName
FROM            ExecutionLogStorage INNER JOIN
                         Catalog ON ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID = Catalog.ItemID
where Catalog.[Type] = 2
GROUP BY ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, Catalog.Name, ExecutionLogStorage.UserName
ORDER BY HitCount DESC
```

**2nd query:**

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[SiteId]
      ,[DirName]
      ,[LeafName] 
FROM [Report_SharePoint_Site].[dbo].[AllDocs]
where id in (
'9DA9CBF1-9888-49B6-ACC2-BC12CA18848B',
'104C8176-5482-4261-AEC7-98D28E478DC1',
'20279F44-9725-436A-A5E1-020FA18EA4AA',
'C86C8213-4E17-452D-8665-BB20146DA31C')
```

End result looks like this in Excel
[image]

Comment: No idea if what you're doing makes sense but in terms of just the most direct answer: `SELECT * FROM ( *Put Query 1 here without ORDER BY*) x JOIN ( *Query 2*) y ON y.ID = x.ReportID`

Comment: @PreQL: Your suggestion helped. Thanks. I will post it as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran the following query per PreQL advise and it worked like charm.

```
Select * from (
SELECT        ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, COUNT(*) AS HitCount, Catalog.Name, ExecutionLogStorage.UserName
FROM            [MSBI_reportingService].[dbo].ExecutionLogStorage INNER JOIN
                         Catalog ON [MSBI_reportingService].[dbo].ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID = Catalog.ItemID
where Catalog.[Type] = 2
GROUP BY ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, Catalog.Name, ExecutionLogStorage.UserName) X

Join

(SELECT [Id]     
      ,[DirName]
      ,[LeafName] 
FROM [Report_SharePoint_Site].[dbo].[AllDocs]) Y
on
Y.ID = X.ReportID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current context is on the same server, then you can refer to each using a 3-part name of Database.Schema.Table and follow it up with an alias to make referencing it simpler.

```
use MSBI_reportingService;

select
    els.ReportID, 
    count(*) as HitCount, 
    c.Name, 
    els.UserName
from
    ExecutionLogStorage els
    inner join Catalog c ON 
        els.ReportID = c.ItemID
    left join [Report_SharePoint_Site].[dbo].[AllDocs] ad on
        els.ReportID = ad.Id
where 
    c.[Type] = 2
group by 
    els.ReportID, 
    c.Name, 
    els.UserName
order by 
    HitCount desc;
```

If you have to execute the query without being able to join the two tables, for whatever reason, you can store the intermediate result in a table variable or temp table.

```
declare
    @report_detail
table
    (
    ReportID uniqueidentifier not null primary key,
    HitCount int not null,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    UserName varchar(255) not null,
    LibraryName varchar(255) null
    );

use MSBI_reportingService;

insert into @report_detail
    (ReportID, HitCount, Name, UserName)
select
    els.ReportID, 
    count(*) as HitCount, 
    c.Name, 
    els.UserName
from
    ExecutionLogStorage els
    inner join Catalog c ON 
        els.ReportID = c.ItemID
where 
    c.[Type] = 2
group by 
    els.ReportID, 
    c.Name, 
    els.UserName;

use [Report_SharePoint_Site];

update
    rd
set
    LibraryName = ad.LibraryName
from
    [dbo].[AllDocs] ad
    inner join @report_detail rd on
        ad.Id = rd.ReportID;
```

As an aside, a personal gripe of mine is the unnecessary grouping of aggregations because you want the return value of some other columns. If you're grouping by a given unique-ness (like ReportID seems to be), you're often better served Grouping By the logical group, and either aggregating the detail, or joining to the associated dimension for your key. This isn't by any means necessary, but it is the beginning of writing cleaner and better code.

Comment: Thanks for the sql however i didnt wanted to re-invent the wheel drastically. Thanks again